# Importing custom data into Jira issue

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am looking for a simple way to get data displayed in an issue as just plain text. Basically, I want to be able to type in a lookup id in the issue creation and then once the issue is created, it would call one of our web services to retrieve data connected with that ID.

This wouldn't be coming from another issue tracker, but rather straight from one of my databases.

What would be the easiest way of accomplishing this? I would like the workflow to be: Enter id #, hit save, see the data with that ID displayed in the ticket (Doesn't need to be editable, just displayed in the ticket view).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a workflow function that is triggered at Create transition to do the job. There your code can query information from the database and replicate them into JIRA standard and custom fields of the issue itself.

Then you can prevent edition of replicated fields by tuning Edit screen for your issues.

You can also use your function to update field content from time to time, either at transition or in a trigger.

An option is to create some read-only custom fields than query each piece information from the database. It will prevent data replication but it will be probably slow and it does not apply to default fields.